# optocoupler PS2501L-1-F3-A

Tags: pcb-design, opto-isolator, circuit-protection

I hope everyone is doing well.
I am newbie in the electronics world.
The optocoupler is  PS2501L-1-F3-A.
the 'In' is supposed to be the input of a dry contact ( GND or floating state ),

In the previous design I used A simple pull up resistor but my colleague accidently connect the power supply of the dry contact to the input what Leeds to damaging the IC (stm32f4).
I want to protect the stm32f4 IC so I am using an optocoupler.

My question : what will happen IF I connect 24V to the input IN. I added the Diode ss210 to prevent frying the led ( it has a reverse voltage of 6V max )

[image]
[image]

Comment: It should work, but why not describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of "will my solution to the problem I'm not telling you about work?" Are you interfacing with a circuit that switches between 0 and 24 V DC? Hit the [edit] link and put all the info in your question and not in the comments.

Comment: @Transistor Done.

Comment: @Transistor if you accidently connect the power supply to DIN you will damage the optocoupler so I added the external diode ss210 to protect it. Is it a good solution and will work or Not. Thank you very much for your time and the reply

Comment: Why are you connecting the 24 V and 5 V systems together? You shouldn't have to. See my answer below.

Comment: @Transistor Another question plz. if You accidently connect 24V to the cathode of the Led ( the anode at 24V ) will that damage the optocoupler.

Comment: I don't know which circuit you are discussing. If it's the one in my answer then please post the question below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkcwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Proper ways to use the opto-isolator.*

This arrangement maintains electrical isolation between the 24 V circuit and the 3.3 V logic.

There is no need to involve the +5 V supply.