# Double powering relay

Tags: relay, protection

I have a problem with my circuit and I want some help.
I have an input connector connected to a dry sensor. It will send 0 when it's ON. So I made this circuit to protect my CPU.
[image]

My problem here is if someone puts 24V in Input connector, that's why I used 24V in pin 1 of the relay. Is it a good solution? What will happen in that case (24V in pin 1 and 2)?
If it's not, is there another solution using relay?

Comment: Are you working on the same project as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558886/optocoupler-ps2501l-1-f3-a?

Answer (score 2):

You MUST add a current limiting resistor as shown below: -

[image]

The value depends on the type of isolator you are using but, from 24 volts, 2k2 is probably going to be OK. It can be fitted in series with pin 1 or pin 2.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens when there is 24V on pins 1 and 2, as there will be 0V over the LED.

However, without a resistor, setting pin 2 to 0V will damage the LED immediately.